# Structs and pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Pessoa{
    char nome[150];
    struct Datanasc{
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int ano;
    } datanasc;
    char genero;
    char pref;
} pessoa;

typedef struct Aresta{
    int *pont;
    int *pont2;
    int peso;
} aresta;

void leitura(struct Pessoa c1){
    printf("Entrei sua vagabunda\n");
    int diaatual,mesatual,anoatual;
    int numeroalunos;
    int i;
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&diaatual,&mesatual,&anoatual);
    scanf(" %d",&numeroalunos);
    for(i=0;i<numeroalunos;i++){
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", pessoa[i].nome);
        scanf(" %d/%d/%d", &pessoa[i].datanasc.dia,&pessoa[i].datanasc.mes,&pessoa[i].datanasc.ano);
        scanf(" %c %c", &pessoa.genero[i],&pessoa.pref[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<numeroalunos;i++){
        printf(" %[^\n]s", pessoa[i].nome);
        printf(" %d/%d/%d", pessoa[i].dia,pessoa[i].mes,pessoa[i].ano);
        printf(" %c %c", pessoa[i].genero,pessoa[i].pref);
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    pessoa c1;
    leitura(c1);
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?
error in line 29, 30, 31, 35, 36, 37-expected expression before "pessoa"
I am having trouble with my structures. Probably it's something related to the [i]'s I have

Comment: and we're suppose to count line 29.30.31.....?

Comment: Are you familiar with `malloc()`?  If so, you will need to use this to create an array of `pessoa` items based on `numeroalunos`.  Then you can use that variable to store your `scanf` inputs and `printf` in the final for loop.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know stack does not show the number of the line.

Comment: My problem is in function leitura, and  I cannot use malloc or anything after pointers

Comment: `typedef` doesn't declare variables.  It merely defines new types.  `pessoa` isn't a variable, it's a data type.  You can use it to declare actual variables, but it isn't a variable itself, any more than `int` or `double` are.  So, delcare an actual variable, then use the variable in your code rather than the type.

Comment: There is no use of `c1`  here =>> `void leitura(struct Pessoa c1)`

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `pessoa` is a type, not a variable name. So, you cannot possibly write

```
 scanf(" %[^\n]s", pessoa[i].nome);
```

You may want to use a variable of type `pessoa`.

Having said that, C uses pass-by value for function parameter passing. They way you pass `c1` (a normal variable) from `main()` and try to populate that in `leitura()` is not going to serve what you *probably* want. You need to pass an array of type `pessoa` from `main()` and use that inside `leitura()`.

Comment: But `c1` is not an array, it's just a single `pessoa`.

Comment: @Barmar Right, I missed that point. Let me update my answer to remove the downside.

Comment: @MrLister Well, that we don't know. `pessoa *p = malloc (numeroalunos * sizeof *p)` and you're all set. :)

Comment: @MrLister `pessoa.nome[i]` is just a single character, so that's unlikely, and it doesn't work for `pessoa[i].dia`. He probably meant to pass an array of `pessoa`.

Comment: Then OP needs to update his question.